How to determine the dynamical equations of this op amp circuit?

In the above circuit, at the inverting node all of the currents are flowing and I can't find a way to solve this.

Whats a dynamical equation?

You have to assume there is no current flowing at the inverting node - assume ideal opamp theory. That will greatly simplify the analysis and make your problem solvable.

@KnowledgeSeeker The equation(s) of a dynamical system, i.e., a system which exhibits dynamic (evolving over time) behavior. Differential equations.

@TimWilliams isnt finding the transfert function same way to find the PDE?

You'll normally approach a problem like this in the frequency (e.g. Laplace) domain, and reverse transform to get the DE, but many ways are available for simple linear systems.


Call the node connected to R and Rin Vx (or whatever you want to call it).
Do KCL equations at Vx and at the inverting input
Solve both your KCL equations for Vx, and set them equal to each other
You should now be able to rearrange terms to get Vo/Vin in terms of the resistors and capacitors, with no Vx in the equation.


Wouldnt that still leave the capacitor voltage in  the output? Because I found out that $V_{out} = -\frac{R_f}{R_i} (V_i - V_x)$
